# Haskell error - More paramaters than needed

Tags: haskell

Evening,

I have the function

```
partialDecode :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String
partialDecode [] y = y -- If we have gone through all guesses we may return the string
partialDecode x y = partialDecode (drop 1 x) replace ((fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y)) -- Recurse over the function: Drop the leading element in the list of guesses and substitute every occurrence of the guess in the string
```

However, when I run it ghci returns an error saying that I am providing 3 paramters instead of 2 when recursing. I am not sure what this means, I am providing a list of tuples in (drop 1 x) and a string in replace ((fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y))

Suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: You should read the error messages more closely, they carry useful information. Certainly the error about "3 paramters instead of 2" also mentioned *which* function was being called with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: Another tip: x !! 0  is usually written as head x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
partialDecode (drop 1 x) replace ((fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y))
```

Passes these arguments to `partialDecode`:

- `(drop 1 x)`
- `replace`
- `((fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y))`

You can reparenthesize it:

```
partialDecode x y = partialDecode (drop 1 x) (replace (fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y))
```

Or use `$`:

```
partialDecode x y = partialDecode (drop 1 x) $ replace (fst (x !! 0) snd (x !! 0) y)
```

Looks like you should do the same thing with `fst` and `snd`, too:

```
partialDecode x y = partialDecode (drop 1 x) $ replace (fst $ x !! 0) (snd $ x !! 0) y
```

Comment: Changed it to partialDecode x y = partialDecode (drop 1 x) $ replace (fst $ x !! 0)) (snd $ x !! 0)) y but still getting the same error